# SVG circle rendering as square on mobile

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG circle inside a web page. It's rendering perfectly on desktop but completely square on my mobile browser. The SVG is exported directly from illustrator.

The JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6y3ym4ov/1/) ***IS*** working on my desktop ***AND*** mobile as intended.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" enable-background="new 0 0 250 250" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <circle id="circle" fill="#202020" stroke="#0A0A0A" stroke-width="4" cx="122" cy="125" r="100"/>
    <line id="hour0" fill="none" x1="122" y1="35" x2="122" y2="25"/>
    <line id="hour1" fill="none" x1="172" y1="38" x2="167" y2="47"/>
    <line id="hour2" x1="210" y1="75" x2="199" y2="80"/>
    <line id="hour3" fill="none" x1="212" y1="125" x2="222" y2="125"/>
    <line id="hour4" fill="none" x1="209" y1="175" x2="200" y2="170"/>
    <line id="hour5" fill="none" x1="172" y1="212" x2="167" y2="203"/>
    <line id="hour6" fill="none" x1="122" y1="215" x2="122" y2="225"/>
    <line id="hour7" fill="none" x1="72" y1="212" x2="77" y2="203"/>
    <line id="hour8" fill="none" x1="35" y1="175" x2="44" y2="170"/>
    <line id="hour9" fill="none" x1="22" y1="125" x2="32" y2="125"/>
    <line id="hour10" fill="none" x1="35" y1="75" x2="44" y2="80"/>
    <line id="hour11" fill="none" x1="72" y1="38" x2="77" y2="47"/>
</g>
<g>
    <line id="hourhand" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="5" x1="122" y1="125" x2="122" y2="70"/>
    <line id="minutehand" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" x1="122" y1="125" x2="122" y2="40"/>
    <line id="secondhand" fill="none" stroke="#823441" stroke-width="2" x1="122" y1="125" x2="122" y2="30"/>
    <circle id="bolt" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#202020" stroke-width="4" cx="122" cy="125" r="5.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**What could impact the SVG on my website to cause it to render as a square only on mobile devices?**

*After a little expirmenting - setting the SVG  "R" attribute to 294 fixes it on my mobile. But I still want to know why this is the case...*

Comment: @robertc the question is in **bold** and says "What could impact the SVG on my website to cause it to render as a square only on mobile devices?"

Comment: Sorry for trying to help, good luck getting whatever answer you're looking for