# SVG circle rendering as a square on Android (phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, svg, geometry

I have a very strange issue with how my phonegap application is rendering SVG, more specifically the circle on my Android device.

Considering the following code:

```
<svg class="gauge" width="320" height="320">
    <circle cx="160" cy="160" r="158" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke: rgb(224, 224, 224); stroke-width: 2px;"></circle>
    <g class="pointerContainer">
        <circle cx="160" cy="160" r="94" style="fill: rgb(70, 132, 238); stroke: rgb(102, 102, 102); opacity: 1;"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The code above works perfectly in most browsers, it shows up correctly when using debugging via chrome inspect and usb debuggin (see screenshot)[image]

However, when I actually launch the application and test on my device, those circles are rendering as squares.

[image]

Moreover, I have also noted than when I decrease the radius (for instance, to 40) it magically starts rendering correctly.

Details:
Phone: HTC M8

PhoneGap Version: 4.2.0-0.24.2

Android Version: 5.0.1

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; HTC One_M8 Build/LRX22C) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/40.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: This seems like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491997/svg-circle-rendering-as-square-on-mobile - tweaking the value of r seems to fix this (I assume you'd apply a transform afterwards to get it back to the size you want)

Comment: This did not work for me, at a certain r value, it did show the circle, but the r was way too small for what I was trying. For instance, in the example above, I got the square until the 94 dropped to something like 50. As soon as it went up to 51, it would go square. Dynamically tweaking the r value did not work.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to add a viewbox, and use double the units. It's clearly a bug, so you might have to be creative about reverse engineering what's triggering it.